# Unexpected Lines under TextInput in React Native Android App

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I am building an app using React Native and I get a weird unexpected line below every TextInput on my physical android device as shown below in the picture. Also, the lines don't show up in the iOS simulator.

[image]

My code for the **Input** Component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { TextInput, View, Text } from 'react-native';

const Input = ({ value,  onChangeText, placeholder, secureTextEntry }) => {
  const { inputStyle, labelStyle, containerStyle } = styles;

  return (
    <View style={containerStyle}>
      <TextInput
        secureTextEntry={secureTextEntry}
        placeholder={placeholder}
        autoCorrect={false}
        style={inputStyle}
        value={value}
        onChangeText={onChangeText}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = {
  inputStyle: {
    color: '#000',
    paddingRight: 5,
    paddingLeft: 5,
    fontSize: 14,
    lineHeight: 23,
    flex: 2,
  },
  containerStyle: {
    height: 40,
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    borderColor: '#ddd'
  }
};

export { Input };
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to [React docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html#textinput) to remove the border:

```
<TextInput underlineColorAndroid='transparent' />
```

> TextInput has by default a border at the bottom of its view. This border has its padding set by the background image provided by the system, and it cannot be changed. Solutions to avoid this is to either not set height explicitly, case in which the system will take care of displaying the border in the correct position, or to not display the border by setting underlineColorAndroid to transparent.

Also you can try to disable **autoCorrect** tag. It might help too:

```
<TextInput autoCorrect={false} />
```

Credits:

1. [underlineColorAndroid](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html#textinput)
2. [autoCorrect](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/5424)

Comment: underlineColorAndroid works. autoCorrect has no effect on this for me.

Answer (score 0):

Border on the bottom in input is natural behaviour for Android, for iOS there is not border bottom.